# WooCommerce is not using my custom templates

Tags: wordpress, templates, woocommerce

I have `woocommerce` folder under `resources/views`.
There is no `templates` folder under my `woocommerce`, but my project seems to only use the templates from `plugins/woocommerce`.

It does not recognize my own custom WooCommerce template files.
I have re-installed WooCommerce, set permalinks twice, recreate shop page.

I use **Sage 10** as my theme builder, and ACF for blocks. I don't see any errors on the console.

Does anyone have any idea why?

It's my first WooCommerce project, so I'm very new.

Comment: What do you mean under resources/views? Woocommerce templates should be in the theme base folder: `sage/woocommerce`. That's it.

Comment: See [Override WooCommerce templates via your child theme](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=override+WooCommerce+templates+via+your+child+theme)